# Amazon Alexa custom skill and smart home skill. Control devices

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I try to implement devices control from Alexa.
I created smart home skill and successfully added user authorization.
I can turn on/off my devices. I understand, that I can add new commands (like stop, play last video, get status and etc.) only using custom skills. But on the basis of this knowledge, I still can not figure out. Can I control devices using additional commands?
For example "Alexa, ask manager to play bedroom TV last video" or "Alexa, ask manager get kitchen camera status".

Comment: can you share your sample code or block diagram that how you made device discovery using alexa?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can control.. Refer this project with sample code and steps to interact with amazon alexa. This will help you to get start from the basics.

https://github.com/krvarma/particle-alexa-smart-home-skill